# Speed out a command

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

How can I speed up the following line of code:

```
df['distance'] = df.apply((lambda row: vincenty(row['Lon'],row['Lat'],row['lon'], row['lat'])), axis=1)
```

df is a very large dataframe.
vincenty is a function in Cython (https://github.com/dmsul/cyvincenty)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue and greatly sped up the performance

Answer (score 0):

The vectorized form should be faster. Use it with the values of each column, since each expected input can be a NumPy array:

```
vincenty(df['Lon'].values, df['Lat'].values, df['lon'].values, df['lat'].values)), axis=1)
```